# Powershell script runs fine on Windows 2008 R2 but does nothing on Windows 2012 R2

Tags: sql-server, powershell, powershell-4.0

I am new to Powershell and I am not sure what to do in regards to the following issue that I am experiencing.

I have the following script that I use to copy the SQL BAK files from my server to my NAS. I consider this a safety measure to make sure that I have a copy of the SQL BAK file outside of my server. The way this script works is very simple. Simply create a SQL job and make sure that "Type:Powershell" is selected, schedule the job and presto change-o! Your BAK files will be copied remotely to your NAS. This script works perfectly fine with Windows 2008 R2 however it does not on Windows 2012.

When I run the SQL job on a Windows 2012 R2 server the job reports that it ran successfully. However when I check the NAS folder no files are copied. I check the logs and the logs reports that the job ran successfully as well.

```psh
param
(
[Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$true)] [string]$SrcFolder,
[Parameter(Position=1, Mandatory=$true)] [string]$TgtFolder
)

##copy

robocopy $SrcFolder i:\sqlbackups $TgtFolder \as2\sqlbackups\SERVERNAME /e /copy:dat /log+:i:aslog\log.txt

##set exit code
$exit = $lastexitcode -band 24

exit $exit
```

So I proceeded to put on my troubleshooting hat to determine why this script was failing to copy the files. I first checked to see if I could run the robocopy cmd without the powershell syntax. So I opened a command (admin) shell and I ran the following command like so.

```
robocopy i:\sqlbackups \as2\sqlbackups\SERVERNAME /e /copy:dat
```

As I expected to see this command ran just fine with no issues.

So I then proceeded to the next step and copied the powershell script to my windows powershell ISE. I ran the script and it prompted me with the following.

> cmdlet at command pipeline position 1 Supply values for the following
>   parameters: SrcFolder:

I never seen this before and I suspect it has something to do with Windows 2012 R2. I want this script to run without any prompting as it does in Windows 2008 R2. Would anyone know how I can resolve this?

Comment: I would check whether you can access the `i`drive on w2012 r2

Answer (score 0):

The reason it prompts in ISE is because you have mandatory parameters that you aren't supplying. It would do the same thing on 2008 R2 / PowerShell 2.0.

I don't think this has to do with why it's not working on 2012 R2 though. It sounds like you're trying to run this directly from SQL server, so I have to assume that the 2 different operating systems indicates that you have 2 different instances of SQL server running.

From that, I suspect that the job is being run as 2 different users, and one of them has access to the NAS and the other doesn't.

Some speculation here, but I will update the answer if you have more details.

Comment: Yes, I am running this from a SQL job agent. This script runs in Windows 2008 R2 within a SQL job with no problem. This is the first time that I am running the same script using Windows 2012 R2. No errors are reported in the log file, the job reports that it ran successfully which is the mystery to me.  I have 42 other SQL servers using the same script on Windows 2008 R2.  This is the first time that I am using Windows 2012 R2 with this script.

Comment: @user36578 what user is running the SQL jobs? If they run from the SQL server agent, then this is probably the service account of the agent. Check the new SQL server's account vs the other 42.

Comment: All of the other SQL servers are using the same AD account for the SQL server agent.  I have two separate AD accounts that I use when configuring a SQL server. One AD account is for the SQL engine and the other is for the SQL agent. Both of these AD accounts have minimal security rights on the Windows 2008 R2 server.  I add these AD accounts to the following in the local security policy of the server, perform volume maintenance task and lock pages in memory.  I am thinking that I may need to add these AD account to additional policies for Windows 2012 R2, but I am not sure which one?